# how to develop touchscreen apps for a big touchscreen using react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, touchscreen

hi im a react developer and was wondering what is the best modern way to create a simple app for modern touchscreen devices. A simple app with one page, some links which lead to assets which can be viewed.

Comment: Do you mean a native app or a website?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say what is best, because it would just be an opinion, but if you are already a react dev, [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/) would allow you to jump in fairly quickly with mobile app development. If you are just looking to make a web app, You will be able to accomplish everything you would like to do in standard React.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a mobile application, you can start using React Native. One way to quickly get into development with React Native is to use Expo https://expo.dev/

You could also create a Progressive Web App, which is basically like a web app, but installable.